# How to check if User has registrated before (Firebase Auth)?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to check if User has registrated before with their **Phone Number** on the client Side (Firebase Auth)? 
Im using Swift 5 and Xcode 10

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with the client SDK. An open API for looking up phone numbers in an app could have privacy implications.

However, you can build your own check via the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users):

```
admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // User with provided phone number is already registered.
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // if error.code 'auth/user-not-found' thrown,
    // then the user does not exist.
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```